# Themes/Skins doesn't work any more in VS2008

Tags: asp.net, themes, skin

I couldn't make the theme/skin thing work in VS2008. Same asp.net2.0 code works fine in VS2005.

I am using Masterpage, and inside content page I would have something like:

`<asp:Button ID="testid" runat="server" SkinID="RedBlueButton" Text="TestButton"></asp:Button>`

and in the App_Themes/Default/button.skin file, I would have something like

`<asp:Button SkinID="RedBlueButton" runat="server" 
  BackColor="Blue" 
  ForeColor="Red" 
  Font-Name="Arial" 
  Font-Size="9px" />`

but the button still shows white. Anybody have any idea why？ Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the theme is specified in web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it worked again when I explicitly add Theme="Default" in the  `<%@ Page >`  directive. However, it still complains that the "Default" is an invalid theme name even though all my theme files are under App_Themes/Default/